# SQL - How to query temporary table from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that is meant to create a temporary table and insert monthly periods.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sprPeriod
@Number FLOAT, @end_date DATETIME
AS

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WorkingDays') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #WorkingDays

CREATE TABLE #WorkingDays 
    (Day_Name VARCHAR(10), Day_Nr FLOAT, FromDate DATETIME, ToDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO 
    #WorkingDays (Day_Name, Day_Nr, FromDate, ToDate)
VALUES 
    ('Monday', -7, DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,@end_date)), @end_date),
    ('Tuesday', -6, DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,@end_date)), @end_date),
    ('Wednesday', -5, DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,@end_date)), @end_date),
    ('Thursday', -4, DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,@end_date)), @end_date),
    ('Friday', -3, DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(dd,1,@end_date)), @end_date)

WHILE @Number > 
        (
        SELECT 
            DATEDIFF(mm,MIN(WD.FromDate),MAX(WD.ToDate))+1 
        FROM 
            #WorkingDays WD
        )

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO 
            #WorkingDays (Day_Name, Day_Nr, FromDate, ToDate)
        VALUES
            ('Monday', -7, (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD), (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD)),
            ('Tuesday', -6, (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD), (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD)),
            ('Wednesday', -5, (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD), (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD)),
            ('Thursday', -4, (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD), (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD)),
            ('Friday', -3, (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD), (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1,MIN(WD.FromDate)) FROM #WorkingDays WD))
    END 

END;
```

I then attempt the following:

```
EXEC sprPeriod '12', '31 July 2015'    
SELECT * FROM #WorkingDays
```

But receive the following error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Invalid object name '#WorkingDays'.
```

I am not sure why the temporary database cannot be retrieved. I have tried removing the DROP TABLE section but I purposively put this before the loop so it didn't drop it by mistake.

What do I need to change in order to query the temporary database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in your `SELECT` query as pointed below. You can't access the local temporary table outside the scope of stored procedure cause it doesn't exists anymore. If you really want to access then consider using a `Global temporary table` of the form `##WorkingDays` or a `non temporary persistent table`

```
EXEC sprPeriod '12', '31 July 2015'    
SELECT * FROM #WorkingDays // Here
```

Answer (score 3):

Temporary tables created inside the procedure are dropped automatically when the procedure ends. If you need to have the table outside the procedure, you'll have to create it before you call the procedure, or you need to return the data with select in the procedure and use insert into #xxx exec procedurename.